# Can I use Pure AspectJ and Spring AOP together?

Tags: spring, aop, aspectj, spring-aop

I am in a situation that I need to use pure AspectJ for logging the system. But the system is already using Spring AOP also. How can I achieve(configure) that while Spring AOP is working , I use AspectJ without touching spring? 
Hope to get help, thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do any special configuration, it will work out of the box. You only need to take into consideration that AspectJ advices will have higher precedence than Spring AOP advices, since AspectJ works directly on the byte code of your classes, while Spring AOP creates proxies around classes to do his work, and only works with Spring managed beans.